# AngularJS is failing to load module

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs

First of all background on my environment. I'm using Windows7, StS IDE, and pivotal tc server, google Chrome.

I built a angularJS app. Below is the code for my index.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>

   <script src="<c:url value="resources/js/angular.min.js"/>"></script>
   <script src="<c:url value="resources/js/angular-route.min.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="resources/js/angular-resource.min.js"/>"></script>
     <script src="<c:url value="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>

   <script src="<c:url value="app/view1/FormView.js"/>"></script>
   <script src="<c:url value="app/view1/controller.js"/>"></script>
       <script src="<c:url value="app/view1/services.js"/>"></script>

   <script src="<c:url value="app/view2/Form2View.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="app/view2/controller.js"/>"></script>
           <script src="<c:url value="app/view2/service.js"/>"></script>

   <script src="<c:url value="app/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>

            <script src="<c:url value="app/myApp.js"/>"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value ="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value ="app/view1/app.css"/>">


  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body  data-ng-app= "myApp">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">LookUpCodeStyle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">AccountMaster</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div data-ng-view></div>


  <!-- In production use: 
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->



</body>
</html>
```

When deployed on server, it throws following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
Uncaught Error: No module: ngResource
```

But the biggest thing where I define:

```
<body  data-ng-app= "myApp">
```

the eclipse throws an error:

```
Cannot find module with name myApp.
```

I have myApp.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.form',
  'myApp.form2'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Btw, it's loading all the files. I checked in the network.
Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: are you using angularjs v1.3.2?

Comment: Actually no, I'm using AngularJS v1.2.12, sorry for the confusion. It's commented out.

Comment: what is `myApp.form` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ngResource to your myApp module.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute', 
    'ngResource', 
    'myApp.form',
    'myApp.form2'
 ])
```

Comment: No that doesn't work either! Are there any good tutorials on Batarang? Or Integrating Spring and Angular? Because this project was working fine when deployed in http server with nodejs.

Comment: Have a look at these:http://java.dzone.com/articles/angularjs-single-page-app http://javahonk.com/spring-mvc-angularjs-integration/

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late but I did use Java Honk link! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with AngularJS for Eclipse: `Cannot find module with name MyApp`, even though `MyApp` was listed in the Angular Explorer. A workaround is to unchain `config` from the `MyApp` declaration, like so:

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.form',
    'myApp.form2'
  ]);
  app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
   }]);
```